# Unit testing using spock for Amazon Dynamodb

Tags: java, unit-testing, nullpointerexception, spock

I am new in using dynamodb, and I tried to do uniting testing on one of the method.

When I try to mock

```
DeleteItemSpec deleteItemSpec = new DeleteItemSpec().withPrimaryKey(new PrimaryKey("id", id, "date", date).withConditionExpression("id = :id")
```

It returns `NPE`. How can I mock this with many properties?

Sorry for such a dumb question, but tried whole night for solution.

```java
public void delete(String id) {
    Item item = null;
    Iterator<Item> iterator = getId(id);
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        item = iterator.next();
        DeleteItemSpec deleteItemSpec = new DeleteItemSpec()
            //get null pointer on below line
            .withPrimaryKey(new PrimaryKey("id", id, "date", item.getString("date")))
            .withConditionExpression("id = :id")
            .withValueMap(new ValueMap()
            .withString(":id", id))
            .withReturnValues(ReturnValue.ALL_OLD);

        try {
            table.deleteItem(deleteItemSpec);
        } catch (Exception e) {e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
            throw new dynamoDBException("...")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So, `iterator.next()` evaluated as null?

Comment: No the iterator returns as an Mock object from table.query(_)

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please learn what an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) is, then help us understand and reproduce your problem by editing your question accordingly. I like to see a full sample class with package name and imports and a full Spock test, so I can copy, paste, compile and run your test. Even if your test does not work now, show us what you tried and how far you got. From what I understand now this question could be a duplicate of one I answered before about [Spock-testing fluent APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57305121/1082681).