# Unit Testing RxJava Flowable using spock

Tags: unit-testing, rx-java, rx-java2, spock, reactive-streams

I have below snippet for fetching data from MongoDB using `com.mongodb.reactivestreams.client.MongoClient` and `Flowable`

The snippet goes like:

```java
Flowable
  .fromPublisher(
     mongoClient
      .getDatabase(mydb)
      .getCollection(mycollection)
      .find()
      .limit()
  )
  .firstOrError()
  .toMaybe()
  .doOnError(error -> { /* somecode */ })
```

I tried mocking every step of this fluent expression, e.g.

```java
MongoDatabase someDb = Mock(MongoDatabase)
mongoClient.getDatabase(mydb) >> somedb
```

but on doing this somehow the test keeps running.

What is the correct way to unit test this using Spock?

Answer (score 0):

Fluent interfaces are a PITA to mock, my strategy is to put those calls into a separate class / method and mock that. And then to test the fluent part in an integration test.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Leonard's idea, you might also want to look into implementing a special `ThisResponse implements IDefaultResponse` which always returns the mock instance for every mock method call and using that like `Mock(defaultResponse: ThisResponse.INSTANCE)` for your fluent API class(es). This works nicely as long as the fluent API methods used in the test are supposed to return `this` or at least another object of the given type. Only where another type is returned, you need to stub something.

Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57305121/1082681) for more details. As soon as you update your question with a little [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), you may also ask follow-up questions if you have any problems using that solution.

---

**Update 2022-03-08:** I re-wrote the linked answer after learning about the special behaviour of `EmptyOrDummyResponse` for methods returning the mocked type. I am also describing now the related Spock 2 syntactic sugar syntax there.